# How can I limit the execution/request time of a (synchronous) .net WebApi request?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a .net MVC application with some `Controllers` and some `ApiControllers`.

The ApiControllers only went live recently, and looking in IIS some of the requests continue seemingly unendingly (the non WebApi ones are fine). 
This is causing the CPU to max out on the servers.

I realise I  need to address the problem that they are running so long, but I'd like for them to timeout if they do, and I can't work out how to make this happen.

The servers as AWS Windows instances behind an AWS load balancer. The load balancer has a 30s idle timeout.

I have configured the IIS `executionTimeout` to 30s (I am unclear if this constrains synchronous WebApi requests, but seemingly not).

**My question is how can I limit the execution/request time of a WebApi request?**

For reference, here is an example endpoint:

```
public class ProfileController : ApiController
{

[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/profile/delete/{entryId}")]
public ApiResult Delete(int entryId)
{
    var sharedContent = _sharedContentRepository.Get(entryId);

    if (sharedContent == null)
    {
        var response = new ApiResult(false, "Shared Content not found");
        return response;
    }

    var currentUser = _userService.CurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null || currentUser.Id != sharedContent.SharedBy.Id)
    {
        return new ApiResult(false, "Not user's shared content to delete");
    }

    sharedContent.Hidden = true;

    return new ApiResult(true);
}
...
```

Comment: Learn how to use Task Parallel Library in C# and .NET. Then you can easily add timeout check using your own code.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to do what you suggest, but right now I'm just looking for a configuration. Or to understand why my attempts haven't worked.